# My Jquery variable can't recognize other variable inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm doing a function in Jquery and my code works when I manually add the term inside the find parentheses, the problem is when I change the value to some variable string.

**Code:**

```
var name = $("#certfieldf").val();
var ale = $("#dat").contents().find("td:contains('name')" ).siblings("td").eq(1).text();
```

How can I use `name` inside `td:contains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find("td:contains('" + name + "')" )
```

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot that! Thanks!